# Error retrieving file from firebase cloud storage

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, rest, busboy

I uploaded a form data which contains an image file and some other fields. I uploaded the file image to my firebase cloud storage and added the other form data to my firebase firestore collection with a constructed URL of the file image I uploaded which was like (`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${storageBucket key})/o/${filename}?alt=media`). my upload was successful but I got an error when I tried viewing the file image on my browser using the URL

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}
```

Below is my RestApi Code:

```
exports.addType = (req, res) => {

    const BusBoy = require('busboy');
    const path = require('path');
    const os = require('os');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const busboy = new BusBoy({headers: req.headers});
    let fileName;
    let fileToBeUploaded = {};
    let fields = {};
    busboy.on('field', (fieldname, data)=> {
        fields[fieldname] = data;
    })
    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
        fileName = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;
        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
        fileToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    })
    busboy.on('finish', ()=> {
        let imageUrl;
        
        admin.storage().bucket().upload(fileToBeUploaded.filepath, {
            destination:`Type/${fileName}`,
            resumable: false,
            metadata: {
                metadata: {
                    contentType: fileToBeUploaded.mimetype
                }
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            imageUrl =  `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${fileName}?alt=media`;
            return db.collection('Type').doc(fields.type);
        })
        .then(data => {
            if(data.exists){
                return res.status(400).json({error: `${fields.type} already exist`})
            }
            db.collection('Type').doc(fields.type).set({
                type: fields.type,
                category: fields.category,
                details: fields.details,
                imageUrl
            })
        })
        .then(()=> {
            return res.status(200).json({message: `${fields.type} has been added`});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.code});
        })
    })
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  This is a bug in Firebase Storage.  Access (under Security Rules) requires an "authorization" header - and HTML & Browsers do *not* support added headers for `<img>` tags.  It is *possible* to access such files either by:

- fetching a "long-lived" (i.e. permanent) URL using `ref.getDownloadURL()`, which BYPASSES the Security Rules (useful for images that need to become part of SEO results - fully public)
- OR
- using an asynchronous fetch (fetch or axios or XMLHttpRequest or whatever) while adding the appropriate `authorization:` header.  What *is* the proper value for the header?  It took a fair bit of diving into Google's Github, BUT it turns out it is as simple as `` `Firebase ${JWTToken}` `` (note the space).
- This [gitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5342) discusses it at length, but the solution-for-the-moment is:

### A proposed Browser/Node-side solution

Not the most straight forward, due to browser limitations.  It is NOT possible to add custom headers directly to `<img>` tags, but it IS possible to set an `onError` handler to do an independent fetch.

#### JSX

```
              <img
                src={image}
                //crossOrigin="use-credentials"
                style={whatever}
                alt={whatever}
                onError={errorHandler}
              />
```

where:
{image} is the Firebase Storage URL, which can be entirely programatically generated.
NOTE: the URL *MUST* include the `alt=media` tag (or whatever is appropriate to the file type).  If this parameter is missing, Firebase Storage will return the metadata JSON object.
{errorHandler} see below

#### Javascript

```
//built in React
 const [authorization, setAuthorization] = useState(null);

//Asynchronously fetches users JWT.  Note closure, as useEffect itself must be synchronous
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      (async () => {
        const authToken = await fetchJWT();
        setAuthorization(authToken);
      })();
    }
  }, [user]);

//Technically, this is in my wrapper library - uses the Firebase Auth service to fetch a user's JWT
 export const fetchJWT = async (user) => {
  const thisUser = user || FirebaseAuth.currentUser;
  //the "true" below forces a reset
  const JWT = await thisUser.getIdToken(true);
  return JWT;
 }

//More-or-less copied from firebase-js-sdk/storage/src/implementation/requests.ts
  const addAuthHeader_ = async (headers) => {
    if (authorization !== null && authorization.length > 0) {
      headers["Authorization"] = "Firebase " + authorization;
    }
  };

// handles the actual error event 
  const errorHandler = async (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const target = e.target;
    const src = $(target).attr("src");
    let headers = {};
    addAuthHeader_(headers);
    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };
    await fetch(src, options)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.status === 200 && res.blob();
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          return;
        }
        $(target).prop("src", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      });
  };
```

#### Explanation

*when* the `<img>` tag encounters an error, the errorHandler

- fetches the `src` attribute from the event target.
- It then creates an `options` object for the `fetch()` call, including headers.  The headers get an `authorization` header added, which consists of a string with `` `Firebase ${authortization}` ``
- The resulting fetch is saved as a Blob to local storage, and a URL created with `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, which is then set as the `src` for the target `<img>`.

#### Result

A file (in this case, an image) is fetched from Firebase Storage, following *all* of the Security Rules set therein.  No permanent token needed.  Only authenticated users have access.
(I will note that I use Anonymous User accounts for new users, with appropriate restrictions set on their access)

### Going Forward

I am likely to added a class to `<img>` elements that are intended to show images from Firebase Storage, or possibly examine the URLs.  That way a single errorHandler can be designated to handle all of them.